# Android twitter callback URL error

Tags: android, twitter, callback, twitter4j

Okay so I am creating a twitter clone, the only problem I am having right now is that the callback URL is getting me back to the app but instead giving me a page not found error.

I saw some similar questions here in stackoverflow and followed the steps.

1. I am getting the Authentication URL using the code:

   ```
   public String beginAuthorization(){
    try{
       if(null==currentRequestToken){
           currentRequestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
       }
       return currentRequestToken.getAuthenticationURL();

   }catch (TwitterException te){
       te.printStackTrace();
   }
   return null; }
   ```
2. Next I am retrieving the Access Token using the code:

   ```
   public void setAccessToken(Uri uri) {

   if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
       String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_token");
       try {
           AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(app.currentRequestToken, verifier);
           //shared prefs
           SharedPreferences.Editor e = yambaSharedPrefs.edit();
           e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
           e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, accessToken.getTokenSecret());

           //store log in status
           e.putBoolean(PrefSharedTwitterLoggedIn, true);
           e.apply();
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, StatusActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);

       } catch (TwitterException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }   }
   ```
3. My Callback URL looks like this:

   ```
   public static final String  OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME = "twitter4j-MiYAMBA";public static final String  OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST  = "callback";public static final String  TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME + "://" + OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST;
   ```
4. I have also added the callback URL in the intent filter, like:

   > data android:host="callback" android:scheme="twitter4j-MiYAMBA"

Now I am not sure where the problem might be.

Also here is how the control flows through out the app:

StatusActivity is launched when the app is run, it checks if AccessToken are set or not using a function isAuthorised() which is defined in an Android application class named YAMBAapp, if it is defined then it begins the setup of layout, that is making buttons and stuff visible else it passes the control to a function beginAuthorization(), which starts an Activity named AuthorizationActivity, which gets the Authentication URL and passes it to the WebView, all of this is done in the function onResume, in this function I call another function setAccessToken and pass the 'uri' that has has data using:

```
uri = getIntent().getData();
setAccessToken(uri);
```

I have pasted the code for setAccessToken above.
Also in the manifest I have defined the "data" item in the intent filter of "AuthorizationActivity" and not the "StatusActivity", though it has no effect what so ever.

Please help, I really am stuck for few days now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first, when you launch twitter authentication using default web browser, you will never return back to your main application, once access tokens are received and hence page not found, as url being invalid.

What you need is to load authenticaton using a web view through your own app, now you can override few functioanlities here like when being redirected. here you need to do final processing and terminate web view, which will result into control coming back to your own application rather then seeing page not found in browser.

Example: Here is how you oveerride an webview mechanism, now you create an actvity with theme like dialog or whatever, and load this webview in it with twitter auth url, once user authtenticate himself `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` will be called, here you retrive back verifier and quit..

```
webView.setWebViewClient( new WebViewClient()
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        // your url pattern here
        if( url.contains("callback://twitter4j-MiYAMBA"))
        {

            Uri uri = Uri.parse( url );
            // you get the verifier here
            String oauthVerifier = uri.getQueryParameter( "oauth_verifier" );

            // Do whateever u want here
            ..oauthVerifier.

            //
            // Finish this task, so you return back to activity from where it started
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

I guess this would be enough to finish rest of implementation. more info here '

http://daiwei.lu/2014/01/22/twitter-oauth-flow-on-android/